# Coffeescript + Express.js : efficient way to pass req.session to model classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I don't know if the fact that I'm using CS is relevant.

Anyway: I've defined some classes that I use to handle database objects, but I cannot find a clean way to pass the current user id (found in req.session.user.id) to them.

Is there a better way to achieve this than passing it every time as a parameter in the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I've build a very simple middleware to save some of the session data, some of my config data, etc. in the res.locals object so as to be able to obtain them in various modules. It depends what do you have in your classes: if you have access to the response object or not.

The middleware solution may be a good idea for you too

Comment: sure but then wouldn't I have to pass the res obj every time to the constructor? or is there a way to pass it directly to the class obj?

Comment: it's hard to anwser without any more info on the context and your code structure. But you sure have to pass at least one object to your classes if you want them to access your data. Then this object depends on your structure, and on what you have access to from your classes.

Comment: that is not true. For example data saved in node global var is available everywhere

Comment: yes, but you need something related to the session / request ... so it can't be a global variable! Your only way would be to have global table where you store the sessionID and the value of the session data you want to save.